# Trying to draw an image icon in graphics but it wont work

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw an image icon in graphics but for some reason I can't draw the image. I think I've done everything correct, I don't know why it doesn't work.

I also tried to change from `ImageIcon` to `BufferedImage` and it also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?
this is my code:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Space Ship Game");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DirectionPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

And

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DirectionPanel extends JPanel
{

    private final int WIDTH = 1300, HEIGHT = 900;
    private final int JUMP = 10; 
    private final int IMAGE_SIZE = 31;
    private ImageIcon spaceShipImage;
    private int x, y;

    public DirectionPanel()
    {
        addKeyListener (new DirectionListener());

        x = WIDTH /2;
        y = HEIGHT /2;

        try
        {
            spaceShipImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2.gif"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("sss");
        }
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponenet (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        spaceShipImage.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    }

    private class DirectionListener extends KeyAdapter
    {

      public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
      {

         switch (event.getKeyCode())
         {

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    System.out.println("Dsfdsf");
                    y -= JUMP;
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:              
               y += JUMP;
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
               x -= JUMP;
               break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               x += JUMP;
               break;
         }

         repaint();
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to rename your `paintComponenet` method to `paintComponent` in order to override the `paintComponent` method of the super class. Names are very important in overriding methods. As **Andrew Thompson** suggested adding `@Override` on top of the method you are overriding is very handy to check the signature and typos. A method in child class must have the same signature of that method in the super class in order to override it. Only the access modifier can be increased.

After that if your image `2.gif` is in the same package as your `DirectionPanel` class is, you should remove the `/` before the name of your `2.gif`.

Good Luck.

Comment: *"Names are very important in overriding methods."* That's where `@Override` notation comes in very handy. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't saw the  extra  'e' in painComponenet!

Comment: @Trying_To_Understand, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Maybe you know how can i delete a white background of an image, with the help of graphic function?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson for the hint, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Trying_To_Understand if you don't want the white background, it's better to edit your images in photoshop and save them in `.png` format. Don't try to do this programmatically, it will kill the performance.

Comment: I understand that, but i have an image (background) on my panel and i cannot fit the background of my image (spaceship)  to my background of my panel...

Comment: Sorry it's vague what you are asking. Can you illustrate that? Maybe you want to provide an image or something of what you want.